# Accessing values from ACF sub field (flexible content area) in PHP

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to access the values of a ACF sub field using PHP.

```
$articles = get_posts(
 array(
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'post_type' => array('venues', 'suppliers'),
 )
);


$locations = array();
foreach ($articles as $article) {

    $field = get_field('info_items', $article->ID, false);

    if( have_rows('info_items') ):
        while( have_rows('parent_field') ): the_row();

        $value = get_sub_field('info_location');

        endwhile;

    endif;
    var_dump($value);
    exit();
}
```

In the code above if I `var_dump` the contents of `$field` I get the array showing all the subfields - including the one I want:

> array(3) { [0]=> array(2) { ["acf_fc_layout"]=> string(13)
>   "info_location" ["field_59ea62cf04adf"]=> string(16) "Manchester" }
>   [1]=> array(2) { ["acf_fc_layout"]=> string(10) "info_phone"
>   ["field_59ea634904ae3"]=> string(11) "08009788221" } [2]=> array(3) {
>   ["acf_fc_layout"]=> string(12) "info_website"
>   ["field_59ea635c04ae5"]=> string(32) "https://www.stuffandstuff.co.uk"
>   ["field_5c6802013bb34"]=> string(0) "" } } NULL

I'm trying to retrieve the 'info_location' value - in this example the string 'Manchester'.

The have_rows loop is from the ACF website docs for get_sub_field but doesn't work in this context.

Comment: Check while loop in your code. You need to pass parent field there.

Answer (score 1):

You iterate through posts obtained by the `get_posts()`, so you have to pass post ID as the second parameter of the function [`have_rows()`](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/have_rows/).
By default ID of current post is used.

```
foreach ($articles as $article) {

    $value = null;
    if( have_rows( 'info_items', $article->ID ) ): 
        while( have_rows( 'info_items', $article->ID ) ): the_row();

            $value = get_sub_field('info_location');

        endwhile;

    endif;

    echo "<br>{$article->ID} ";
    var_dump($value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this - should have seen that. Still getting an issue that it's returning bool(false) where it should be returning Manchester. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you change `have_rows()` on both lines?

Comment: Yes changed both

Comment: With your amendment it now prints the article ID and bool(false) for each article. Something very strange going on...